# Has C++ Always Allowed Using A Variable for Array Size?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, size

For some reason, in the past, I recall not being able to do something like:

```
int arraySize;
cin >> arraySize;

int array[arraySize];
```

But recently, I tried this again and its not causing any issues.  I could've sworn before this was something that threw an error in my compiler (macOS Sierra, Xcode 8.1).  Was anything in the language updated to allow this? - I could be entirely remembering incorrectly and this wasn't an issue before, but I'm not sure.  I thought array sizes had to be defined during compilation and the user couldn't pick that (which is where you would implement a dynamic array).

Comment: It's probably compiler extension - don't use it to make code portable

Comment: @W.F. - I dont plan on using it, I'd rather use a vector or a dynamic array, I was just very confused on why this was possible now, all-of-the-sudden.

Comment: Whole `int[N]` is a type in c++ and as such it must be entirely known at compile-time including `N`. I don't think it will ever change...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C++ Standard does not support variable length arrays though some compilers can have their own language extensions that allow to use VLAs in a C++ program.

Thus this code snippet

```
int arraySize;
cin >> arraySize;

int array[arraySize];
```

is not C++ compliant.

Use instead the standard C++ class `std::vector`.

As for C then according to the C Standard implementations may conditionally support VLAs.

You can check whether an implementation supports VLAs.
From the C Standard (6.10.8.3 Conditional feature macros)

> 1 The following macro names are conditionally defined by the
>   implementation:

`__STDC_NO_VLA__`

> The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation
>   does not support variable length arrays or variably modified types.

Answer (score 8):

> Was anything in the language updated to allow this

No. Variable length arrays (aka. VLAs) are a compiler specific extension.

The c++ standard never allowed this (unlike the c99 standard does so contrarily).

Comment: Interesting, Apple must've changed it in Xcode then.

Comment: @joe_04_04 It's not so much about the Xcode IDE, rather than the used toolchain and it's version probably.